# How to apply the count function to every element in a list in R?

Tags: r

Goal: count the frequency of nucleotides in each element (each containing 10 characters) from a list.

I have tried:

```
for (i in 1:1074){d10<-count(d10[["i"]],1)}
```

I keep getting  "Error in seq.default(from=1+start,to=length(seq),by=by):wrong sign in 'by' argument

What I want:

```
A G C T
3 4 2 1
A G C T
2 0 5 3
```

from the first element to the last element (1:1074).

Comment: Can you show an example of input data

Comment: This is a good opportunity to use the R lapply function. Please take a look at the documentation for that function, it is used to apply a function to each element of a list and return the result as a new list.

You'll have to figure out how to actually count the nucleotides in each list element, and then how to combine the results into a single answer, but if you break it down into those pieces you should be on your way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is indeed nucleotides, you can do:

```
library(Biostrings)
d10 = list("ATGCATGCAT","TTTAAAGGGC","CGCGCGCGCG")

alphabetFrequency(DNAStringSet(unlist(d10)))[,1:4]
     A C G T
[1,] 3 2 2 3
[2,] 3 1 3 3
[3,] 0 5 5 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Using `dplyr` and some made-up data:

```
library("dplyr")

df <- data.frame(element = c(rep("el1", 10), rep("el2", 10)),
                 character = c(rep("A", 5), rep("G", 5), rep("T", 5), "C", "C", "C", "A", "G"))


df %>% group_by(element, character) %>% 
      summarize(n = n())

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   element [2]
  element character     n
  <fct>   <fct>     <int>
1 el1     A             5
2 el1     G             5
3 el2     A             1
4 el2     C             3
5 el2     G             1
6 el2     T             5
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `table` from `base R`

```
table(df)
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(element = c(rep("el1", 10), rep("el2", 10)),
                 character = c(rep("A", 5), rep("G", 5), rep("T", 5), "C", "C", "C", "A", "G"))
```